# On first click animate, on second reverse animation: how to?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have read couple of others questions like this, but they are basically using deprecated `.toggle()` function.
I'm struggling to achieve that `div#p` on first click goes right and on second click goes back to starting position.

I wrote this code:

```
$(function(){
    $("#p").on("click", function(){
        if ($("#p").data("right") == 'n') {
            $("#p").animate({marginLeft:"50"}, 500);
            $("#p").data("right", 'y');
        } else {
            $("#p").animate({marginLeft:"0"}, 500);
            $("#p").data("right", 'n');
        }
    })
})
```

which is working *with one big error*: **after page is loaded, first click fires nothing**.(second and other clicks are switching animation action correctly).

What's the catch here, how to correct this?

Comment: Provide the HTML, surely you haven't set **data-right** properly

Comment: this depends on default status of the p, can you create a demo using jsfiddle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(function(){
    $("#p").on("click", function(){
        var state = parseInt( $(this).css('margin-left'), 10 ) > 0;
        $(this).animate({marginLeft : state ? 0 : 50}, 500);
    });
});
```

or with data, and accounting for undefined data values :

```
$(function(){
    $("#p").on("click", function(){
        var state = $(this).data("right");
        $(this).animate({marginLeft: (state ? 50 : 0)}, 500);
        $(this).data("right", !state);
    });
});
```

Comment: Your first solution is right, with second somehow I get same results as with mine own. Anyway thanks a lot, I've been struggling with this for hours...

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to fetch `data-right` but I don't think you have set that already. You should set it upon loading of your page so you can actually retrieve it. Either use `.ready()` or just add `data-right` to your `<p>`

Comment: If I declare data-right anywhere before if-else statement, I've got second animation automatically fired with first. I've tried that.

Comment: Are you double-clicking? It's an if-else statement, it can't fire both at once...

Comment: No, but now I suspect something might be wrong with my browser, even if I know that this is very rare case...

Answer (score 0):

I wrote similar code with ideas from this thread. This is for 1 div but it can be rewrite to tag "p" as you used in this thread.

```
$( ".content" ).click(function() {
    if( $( this ).hasClass( "vysun" ) ){
      var status = true;
      $( this ).removeClass( "vysun" );
    }
    else{
      var status = false;
      $( this ).addClass( "vysun" );
    }
    $( this ).animate({width : status ? "33%" : "100px"}, 1500, "linear");
});
```